# How long is my first class medical certificate good for as a third class certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

My first class medical exam was on 01/07/2020. I am 64 years old. Is it now valid as a third class medical certificate until 01/31/2022?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I assume you’re asking about FAA regulations so  I added that tag to your question. For questions about regulations, please always mention the country or regulations that you’re asking about.

Comment: Is there a wrinkle to this question that I'm not seeing?  Because I would presume that someone in need of a first class med would know where to go for the answer.  Or do you just want someone else to look it up for you?  Lack of effort generally warrants a downvote...

Answer (score 1):

You hold a First Class Medical Certificate, not a Third Class Medical Certificate.  As you are over the age of 40, the First Class Medical expires 24 calendar months after the date of issuance on your medical certificate, BUT ONLY IF you are conducting an operation requiring a recreational pilot, Private pilot, or Flight Instructor Certificate.  See §61.23(d)

Comment: Technically he has until January 2021 to exercise the privileges of a commercial pilot certificate.